# MS Project VBA Copy Finsh Date to Finsh 1

Tags: vba, ms-project

Im new to VBA, and looking for a simple code to copy say, my current finish and start dates to finish1 and start1

So I can track a shift trend

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple procedure that loops through the tasks in the active schedule and copies the start/finish dates into start1/finish1.

```
Sub CopyDates()

    Dim t As Task
    For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
        t.Start1 = t.Start
        t.Finish1 = t.Finish
    Next t
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at questions tagged with [ms-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-project) to find more examples of what you can do with vba.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the method Rachel provided, you can use the [BaselineSave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.baselinesave) method of the MS Project Application object. Even though it's called *BaselineSave*, the method has optional arguments that will allow you to copy current dates into any of the start/finish fields without setting the actual baseline of the tasks. I prefer this method since it can accomplished in a single line.

```
Sub CopyDates()

    Application.BaselineSave All:=True, Copy:=pjCopyCurrent, Into:=pjIntoStart_Finish1

End Sub
```